# Eventsource golang : how to detect client disconnection?

Tags: go, server-sent-events

I'm developing chat rooms based on Twitter hashtag with Server sent events, with the package https://github.com/antage/eventsource

I have a problem concerning the disconnection of the client. I run a goroutine to send messages to the client, but when the client disconnects, the goroutine still runs.

I don't know how to detect on the server side that the client is disconnected.

```
func (sh StreamHandler) ServeHTTP(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    es := eventsource.New(
        &eventsource.Settings{
            Timeout:        2 * time.Second,
            CloseOnTimeout: true,
            IdleTimeout:    2 * time.Second,
            Gzip:           true,
        },
        func(req *http.Request) [][]byte {
            return [][]byte{
                []byte("X-Accel-Buffering: no"),
                []byte("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *"),
            }
        },
    )

    es.ServeHTTP(resp, req)

    go func() {
        var id int
        for {
            id++
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
            es.SendEventMessage("blabla", "message", strconv.Itoa(id))
        }
    }()

}
```

Answer (score 14):

As of December 2018, [apparently CloseNotifier is deprecated](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#CloseNotifier). The recommended solution is to use the `Request` Context. The following worked for me:

```
done := make(chan bool)
go func() {
        <-req.Context().Done()
        done <- true
}()
<-done
```

Comment: Do you have a complete example that fits in with the original question as I couldn't get this to work?  Thanks.

Comment: @anderspitman Is there a way to differentiate between a graceful client disconnect versus an abrupt client disconnect using this?

Comment: @ymerej not that I know of. Detecting TCP disconnects can actually be rather tricky.

Comment: no need for the `done` channel - just use `<-req.Context().Done()` directly - and use `select` with `default` to do a non-blocking poll.

Comment: Note this is answered better in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57246852/go-http-context-not-able-to-capture-cancellation-signal-when-request-has-body-c

Answer (score 6):

You can use [CloseNotifier](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#CloseNotifier) which lets you know if the underlying http connection has closed. Like:

```
notify := w.(http.CloseNotifier).CloseNotify()
go func() {
    <-notify
    // connection close, do cleanup, etc.
}()
```

HTH

Answer (score 3):

You could check `ConsumersCount()`:

```
    go func() {
        var id int
        for es.ConsumersCount() > 0 {
            id++
            es.SendEventMessage("blabla", "message", strconv.Itoa(id))
            time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
        }
        fmt.Println("closed")
    }()
```

Kinda hacky, but it seems to work.

You may be better off using a different package or rolling your own so you could have better control over the lifetime of your goroutines. You can detect a closed connection on `.Write` (which this package isn't exposing).

If you want here's an example chat server in TCP: [chat-server](https://github.com/golang-book/bootcamp-examples/blob/master/week2/day2/chat-server/main.go). 
And a video tutorial to go with it: [tutorial](https://youtu.be/cNxfgXrHeAg?t=5m48s).

The same basic pattern should work for SSE.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My problemme is that the package i'm using doesn't propose the ConsumerCount() function.

Answer (score 0):

This approach will work (tested with Go 1.22)

```golang
func (sh StreamHandler) ServeHTTP(resp http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {

    go func(done <-chan struct{}) {
        <-done
        fmt.Println("message", "client connection has gone away, request got cancelled")
    }(req.Context().Done())

    // .. the rest of your code here

}
```