# Go http context not able to capture cancellation signal when request has body (curl, postman)

Tags: http, go, curl, postman

The problem can be reproduced with the below simple go code snippet：

Simple go http server:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    go func(done <-chan struct{}) {
        <-done
        fmt.Println("message", "client connection has gone away, request got cancelled")
    }(r.Context().Done())

    time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!\n", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Start above http server, if i send one simple `GET` request with curl(postman also) like:

```
curl -X GET http://localhost:8080/
```

then press `Ctrl+C` to terminate the request, then i am able to see the printed message at server side:

```
message client connection has gone away, request got cancelled
```

**above is the correct behaviour i expect**: to simulate the situation that when client is gone the server can capture it and then cancel all the unnecessary work as early as it can.

But when i send one POST request with request body, this expected behaviour **doesn't** happen, the `<-done` signal was captured until the request deadline meet.

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:8080/ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{}'
```

To summarize my questions:

1. Why and how the curl(postman) `GET`, `POST` (with or without request body) request make such a difference?
2. How should i handle this case properly with go context package, i mean to capture the client is gone signal as soon as it can, and so further to cancel the server side unnecessary work to release the resources as early as it can.

Comment: Re context. Pass r.Context() to any subtask e.g. SQL query; http/gRPC call etc. - and that will chain context cancelation per design. The sub tasks will chain a cancellation error as a result. If you want to poll the request context in your own code e.g. a wait-loop then use `select` on the context channel along with your wait-timer channel.

Comment: @colminator thanks for the reply, i understood that, above code is just build for reproducing the problem i encountered: i am NOT able to capture the cancellation signal in the POST request case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Read the request body to detect when the client closes the connection:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    go func(done <-chan struct{}) {
        <-done
        fmt.Println("message", "client connection has gone away, request got cancelled")
    }(r.Context().Done())

    io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, r.Body) // <-- read the body
    time.Sleep(30 * time.Second)
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!\n", r.URL.Path[1:])
}
```

The net/http server checks for closed connections by reading the connection.  No reads are started until the application starts reading the request body (if any).

Comment: I tried to find any notes about this on go doc, but I found nothing, yet it does solve OP's problem. do you have a link or documentation related to this one?

Comment: ah, ic, excellent , spent me two three hours to try to understand this behaviour!

Comment: I do not know of any documentation for this. The behaviour follows from the fact that read or write is the only way to detect a closed connection in Go.

Comment: @CeriseLimón i found out that i must read the WHOLE request body, then the detection works, if i only read like a few bytes, the connection closure event will NOT be detected, is there any way to avoid reading the WHOLE request body but not losing the detection ability? (my purpose is to delay the request body reading a bit, so that if the client has already gone away then i don't bother to read the request body anymore)

Comment: @BaytaDarell i am able to cancel the request even with POST call as well. I'm using go 1.18 darwin/amd64 is it platform dependent?