# Go context handler is there any way to detect the underlying connection (client) has gone away without fully reading the request body

Tags: http, go, tcp

Firstly as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57247158/7658313) and its answer explained, when the server had **fully** read the request body everything works as expected, i mean when the client has gone away or get cancelled the server will get notified immediately.

But i am looking for a way that **while not fully reading the request body the server still be able to detect the underlying connection (client) has gone away**, so the server doesn't even bother to try to read the request body anymore.

A bit more context is that i found my Go http server wasted a lot of memories on the request handler's `ioutil.ReadAll(request.Body)` eventually `bytes.makeSlice (2192.03MB 89.02%)`, i mean the handler did a lot of request body readings but then found that actually the caller/client has already timed out/gone away...

So i am thinking of holding the request before going to actually read its body, and if in that stage it already runs into timeout or got cancelled by the client then the server can terminate the handlers chain immediately to save resources, is it possible to go this way?

Or any other better approach to this problem?

Comment: A client that's sending data has not gone away.  Can the application process the request body as a stream instead of slurping the data into memory?  Can the application enforce a limit on the request body size?

Comment: @CeriseLimón the stream manner doesn't make much sense in this situation i feel, i mean only when the server accumulated a full request payload then it can do something meaningful, and there is a limit on each request payload size already, the point here is mainly on how to avoid those unnecessary payload readings (as like client already cancelled the request coz it already run into timeout, or like the connection was already interrupted, but now the situation is only after the sever had read the full payload then be able to detect such events)

Comment: Consider the case where a client writes some data and closes the connection.  The application will read data buffered in the TCP stack before detecting that the connection is closed, but is that enough data to be concerned about?

Comment: @CeriseLimón i think that is the point, what i would like to achieve is that since the connection is already interrupted or client timeout is already reached, if i can detect such events before (now only after) reading the data buffered in the TCP stack then the server can directly discard it coz no point to do anything further (for now i hold the request a bit before reading the data according to the mem usage, and then decide whether to proceed based on the server side timeout setting, but it is not optimal as the client timeout maybe reached earlier or the conn got interrupted earlier)