# Go-gin, context.Done not working as expected

Tags: go, go-gin, go-context

I am trying to use `ctx.Done` (gin context) to cancel processing request and stop go routine when a user refreshes or exits the page. The code below didn't work, what i do wrong?

```golang
respChan := make(chan types.Result)
defer close(respChan)

cCp := c.Copy()

go func() {
    for {
        fmt.Println("check")
        time.Sleep(10000 * time.Millisecond) //long task
        test := []types.ResultTXT{{Txt: "Test Resp"}}
        select {
        case <-cCp.Done():
            fmt.Println("goroutine canceled")
            return
        case respChan <- types.Result{Response: test}:
            fmt.Println("Work end")
            return
        }
    }
}()

select {
case <-c.Done():
    fmt.Println("canceled")
    c.Abort()
    return
case res := <-respChan:
    result := res.Response
    c.HTML(http.StatusOK, "response.html", gin.H{
        "Resp": result,
    })
    return
}
```

I use gin and go in v. 1.8, but i also tried downgrade (to gin 1.7.7 and use `c.Request.Context().Done()`) and result is same.

Comment: Please split two questions into 2 SO questions.

Comment: What result are you expecting here? (nothing in your code will prevent the `time.Sleep(10000 * time.Millisecond)` from waiting 10 seconds). I suspect you might be trying to do something [like this](https://go.dev/play/p/25wEHc46-3-)?

Comment: @Brits Maybe I misspoke/gave the wrong example. See this [one](https://go.dev/play/p/fa5OT0xTOGs), where i used the code from the novalagung ebook. My problem is that context.Done is not triggered after the user cancels request. At first I thought it was gin fault, but it also happens when i used fiber, and the basic http package as in the example i linked to. This case happens only through browser (I checked edge, ie and firefox), when i using curl, it works fine. 
Btw not sure if I should ask separate questions/edit this in this case.

Comment: A [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) always helps (the link you provided is ideal). I believe that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57247158/11810946) will answer your question (add `io.Copy(ioutil.Discard, r.Body) // <-- read the body` above the `select` and your code will work as expected).

Comment: @Brits ah finally! Thank you so much, I don't know why i didn't come across this thread earlier. Yes, this is answer for my question, with gin simply use ctx.FromValue, and with basic http r.ParseForm.